# swift prepareForSegue not working / exc_breakpoint (code=exc_i386_bpt subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function which is not being called at all. I dont event get the preparing for segue printed...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        println("PREPARING FOR SEGUE");
        if (segue.identifier == "ToChatRoom") {
            var chatView:ChatRoomViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ChatRoomViewController;
            var index = coralReefTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row;
            var id = roomIDArray.objectAtIndex(index);
            println("ID IS : \(id)");
            chatView.selectedRoomID = id as Int;
        }
    }
```

I am calling the segue with these lines of code...

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath);
        //performSegueWithIdentifier("ToChatRoom", sender: self);
        let nextController:AnyObject! = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("chatRoom");
        self.showViewController(nextController as UIViewController, sender: nextController);
```

when i uncomment the performSegueWithIdentifier, I get this error: exc_breakpoint (code=exc_i386_bpt subcode=0x0). I was wondering what would be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

Is your ChatRoomViewController inside a Navigation controller? If it is then segue.destinationViewController won't point to the ChatRoom controller? Just a guess. In that case you would need something like:

```
if segue.identifier == "ToChatRoom" {
   let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
   let chatView = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as ChatRoomViewController
   var index = ...
```

When the performSegueWithIdentifier line is commented out, prepareForSegue is never called. The next line explicitly instantiating from the storyboard bypasses the need for it.